# Global constants in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, global-variables

I've a file called **Constants.h**:

```
extern NSString * const BASE_URL;
```

and **Constants.m**:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSString * const BASE_URL = @"http://www.example.org ";
#else
    NSString * const BASE_URL = @"http://localhost";
#endif
```

First question: How can I switch DEBUG to be `True` and `False`?

---

I've a view controller file `MyViewController.m`:

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
#import "Constants.h"

// this doesn't works. see above for the error.
static NSString * const ANOTHER_URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", BASE_URL, @"/path/"];

@implementation HomeViewController

[...]
```

The code doesn't work and returns me this error:

```
error: Semantic Issue: Initializer element is not a compile-time constant
```

How can I fix this?

I need to combine several global string variabile with other strings for create various urls.

---

**UPDATE 1**

Now `Constants.m` is:

```
#import "Constants.h"

#ifdef DEBUG
    #define DEF_BASE_URL "http://www.example.org/"
#else
    #define DEF_BASE_URL "http://localhost/"
#endif

NSString * const BASE_URL = (NSString*)CFSTR(DEF_BASE_URL);
NSString * const API_URL = (NSString*)CFSTR(DEF_BASE_URL "api/");
NSString * const API_SETTINGS_URL = (NSString*)CFSTR(API_URL "settings/");
```

But there is an error on the last line **Parse error: expected ')'**.
Probably I can use CFSTR only with macros. I need to find a way for have all my global variables.

Comment: In Xcode, in the project properties (I forget the exact terms, and don't have my Xcode environment at hand), specify your DEBUG switch in "C preprocessor macros" or some such.  I believe you have to prefix the switch with -D, eg: -DDEBUG.  But I would suggest using a switch name other than "DEBUG" -- something like "MY_DEBUG_MODE" -- so that you don't risk a collision with "DEBUG" elsewhere.... Ah, [here](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/debugging/how-to-create-conditional-log-statements-in-xcode) it is in some detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution A:**

Personally, I would just use a function for `ANOTHER_URL`.

**Solution B:**

If you really want a constant: You should be able to use cstring concatenation rules via `#define`, then pipe that through `CFSTR()`:

```
// defs.h
extern NSString * const BASE_URL;
extern NSString * const ANOTHER_URL;

// defs.m

#ifdef DEBUG
#define DEF_BASE_URL "http://www.example.org"
#else
#define DEF_BASE_URL "http://localhost"
#endif

NSString * const BASE_URL = (NSString*)CFSTR(DEF_BASE_URL);
NSString * const ANOTHER_URL = (NSString*)CFSTR(DEF_BASE_URL "/path/");
```

**Solution C:**

If you want to create just one via initialization, you can also accomplish a function/method local static in C++/ObjC++ translations (then use C or ObjC visibility, where needed):

```
NSString * URL() {
  static NSString * const ANOTHER_URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", BASE_URL, @"/path/"];
  return ANOTHER_URL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude. But I've a problem. If I place `NSString * const ANOTHER_URL = (NSString*)CFSTR(DEF_BASE_URL "/path/");` in `MyViewController.m` before the `@implementation` it returns me an error: `Parse error: Expected )`. I'm sure the code is written okay. Probably I can't use it in viewcontrollers? Why? In `Constants.m` works well without errors.

Comment: @Fred copy/paste error - there was a trailing semicolon following `DEF_BASE_URL`'s value.

Comment: @Fred the trick is valid for c strings, but not CF/NSStrings. so you can build/compose them using c strings, then send the result through `CFSTR` - but it cannot take a form like: `cstring_literal`+`NSString` to produce a CF/NSString literal. so just build them using c strings.

Comment: How? And in your opinion, is the best way to do this? If you have understood well what I'm trying to achieve I've a `BASE_URL` and for each view controllers I've some urls composed by `BASE_URL` and other strings.

Comment: you can also build them so they expand like this: `static NSString* const AAA = @"A""A""A";`

Comment: just substitution, which could take this form: `NSString * const API_SETTINGS_URL = (NSString*)CFSTR(DEF_BASE_URL "api/" "settings/");`. I would just use a function, rather than redefining this value.

Comment: You use function for every variable I need? A function in each view controller, right?

Comment: I would use a function to avoid duplication in programs, which `NSString * const API_SETTINGS_URL = (NSString*)CFSTR(DEF_BASE_URL "api/" "settings/");` would qualify as. For the view controller bit, if they just append a path component, then the view controller can pass that component as an argument to the path builder function.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can tell Xcode to set some preprocessor macros for debug builds. Use the build option 'preprocessor macros'.

For your second question, you can't call an objective-C method to fill a constant, because that stuff isn't available at compile-time. Your best option is to define the global variable, then give it a value in the class 'initialize' method.

```
static NSString * ANOTHER_URL;

+ initialize {
    ANOTHER_URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", BASE_URL, @"/path/"];
}
```

initialize is called before your first instance of the class is created, so it's safe. You'll have to drop the const keyword, but I'm sure you can trust yourself! ;)

Answer (score 0):

#define DEBUG 1 or 0 to disable.

The error is because you are calling a method of NSString while its a compile constant. In other words you are telling the compiler something it simply can't handle. You will need to initialize such a dynamic link on launch, the compiler can't do this for you.

Comment: wow lol # apparently makes a header in an SO post.. sorry for that. anyways you can always do somehting like that in + (void)initialize which is called before your class is created.