# Duplicate symbols for architecture when using global constants

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created the below header file which defines a list of constants that I will use throughout my iOS app.

```
//
//  constants.h
//

#ifndef constants_h
#define constants_h

 NSString* const BaseURL = @"https://.../";
 NSString* const personalFeed = @"https://...";
 NSString* const professionalFeed = @"https://...";

 NSString* const profiles = @"https://...";


 NSString* const profileImages = @"https://...";
 NSString* const profileCollage = @"https://...";

 NSString* const login = @"https://...";
 NSString* const signup = @"https://...";
#endif
```

In all the controllers I need these. I have added their header files, shown below:

```
#include "constants.h"
```

However when I build the app, I get the error:

```
ld: 72 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: Define constants in .m do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031082/global-constants-in-objective-c

Answer (score 4):

The problem happens because you *defined* your constants in a header file, instead of *declaring* them. You need to move definitions into a `.m` file, and replace them with `extern` declarations in the header:

```
//
//  constants.h
//

#ifndef constants_h
#define constants_h

extern NSString* const BaseURL;
extern  NSString* const personalFeed;
...
//
//  constants.m
//
#import "constants.h"

NSString* const BaseURL = @"https://.../";
NSString* const personalFeed = @"https://...";
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't define variables in a header file.  Declare them as `extern` in the header and then define them once in an implementation file.